# customer register in one website store and how he can place order in another website store?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Generally, if customer register with one store then it's details will not use in another store, for this he must have to register with details in another store. then how he can place order with one store details in another store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin view,

under **System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration >**

**Account Sharing Options**,

you'll be able to choose between sharing accounts per **website** or **globally**.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: There, per Website option is select, then after this things happen? Why?

Comment: When i am register in one website and after login from other website (Change store from Front Top menu for Change store), it will give error message with No Username or password are wrong.